# assign uniq identifier or serial number to duplicate or uinq values based on any column

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, perl, uniq

i have input file like this which have duplicates values, i want to give uniq identifier for each uniq value based on first column (col1) mins duplicate rows have same identifier before decimal point based on duplicate value of col1 , any help guyz , thanks in advance.

```
    Ca3CNSNP431180  2428    2435    0   TTTATttt    AT-Hook 1
    Ca3CNSNP431179  2429    2437    0   TTATTttat   AT-Hook 1
    Ca3CNSNP431178  2428    2436    0   TTTATttta   AT-Hook 1
    Ca4CNSNP431177  1384    1388    0   ATTGA   NF-YB;NF-YA;NF-YC   1
    Ca4CNSNP431176  1382    1386    0   AGATT   Myb/SANT;MYB;ARR-B  1
    Ca4CNSNP431175  1382    1386    0   AGATT   GATA;tify   1
    Ca4CNSNP431174  1386    1398    0   tgaAATTTtcatt   TCR;CPP 2
    Ca4CNSNP431174  1386    1398    0   tgaAATTTtcatt   TCR;CPP 2
    Ca4CNSNP431172  1383    1395    0   gattgAAATTttc   TCR;CPP 2
    Ca4CNSNP431172  1383    1395    0   gattgAAATTttc   TCR;CPP 2
    Ca3CNSNP430205  3334    3343    0   tATATAtata  AT-Hook 3
    Ca3CNSNP430205  3334    3343    0   tATATAtata  AT-Hook 3
    Ca3CNSNP430205  3334    3343    0   tATATAtata  AT-Hook 3
```

desired output :

```
identifier  col1    col2    col3    col4    col5    col6    col7
 000001.1   Ca3CNSNP431180  2428    2435    0   TTTATttt    AT-Hook 1
 000002.1       Ca3CNSNP431179  2429    2437    0   TTATTttat   AT-Hook 1
 000003.1       Ca3CNSNP431178  2428    2436    0   TTTATttta   AT-Hook 1
 000004.1       Ca4CNSNP431177  1384    1388    0   ATTGA   NF-YB;NF-YA;NF-YC   1
 000005.1       Ca4CNSNP431176  1382    1386    0   AGATT   Myb/SANT;MYB;ARR-B  1
 000006.1       Ca4CNSNP431175  1382    1386    0   AGATT   GATA;tify   1
 000007.1       Ca4CNSNP431174  1386    1398    0   tgaAATTTtcatt   TCR;CPP 2
 000007.2       Ca4CNSNP431174  1386    1398    0   tgaAATTTtcatt   TCR;CPP 2
 000008.1       Ca4CNSNP431172  1383    1395    0   gattgAAATTttc   TCR;CPP 2
 000008.2       Ca4CNSNP431172  1383    1395    0   gattgAAATTttc   TCR;CPP 2
 000009.1       Ca3CNSNP430205  3334    3343    0   tATATAtata  AT-Hook 3
 000009.2       Ca3CNSNP430205  3334    3343    0   tATATAtata  AT-Hook 3
 000009.3       Ca3CNSNP430205  3334    3343    0   tATATAtata  AT-Hook 3
```

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, i updated my question.

Comment: NO , headers are not mandatory .

Comment: are records already sorted? or could be in arbitrary order?

Comment: i just put headers for better understanding query , they are not required.

Comment: yeah records are sorted in reverse order ,  this the part of actual file only

Answer (score 4):

Short **`awk`** solution:

```
awk '{ printf "%06d.%d\t%s\n",(!a[$1]++? ++c:c),a[$1],$0 }' file
```

- `!a[$1]++` - check for unique value of the 1st field `$1`(used as index for the array `a`)
- `++c` - `c` is a *prefix* value incremented for each unique entry (before decimal point)
- `a[$1]` - *suffix* value (after decimal point) - points to the number of occurrences of the 1st field value `$1`
- `%06d.%d` - output format specificator, where `%06d` points to the size of the *integer part* of the number `d` (size 6 with leading zeros `06`) and `.%d` - the *scale* of the number (*fractional part*)

---

The output:

```
000001.1    Ca3CNSNP431180  2428    2435    0   TTTATttt    AT-Hook 1
000002.1    Ca3CNSNP431179  2429    2437    0   TTATTttat   AT-Hook 1
000003.1    Ca3CNSNP431178  2428    2436    0   TTTATttta   AT-Hook 1
000004.1    Ca4CNSNP431177  1384    1388    0   ATTGA   NF-YB;NF-YA;NF-YC   1
000005.1    Ca4CNSNP431176  1382    1386    0   AGATT   Myb/SANT;MYB;ARR-B  1
000006.1    Ca4CNSNP431175  1382    1386    0   AGATT   GATA;tify   1
000007.1    Ca4CNSNP431174  1386    1398    0   tgaAATTTtcatt   TCR;CPP 2
000007.2    Ca4CNSNP431174  1386    1398    0   tgaAATTTtcatt   TCR;CPP 2
000008.1    Ca4CNSNP431172  1383    1395    0   gattgAAATTttc   TCR;CPP 2
000008.2    Ca4CNSNP431172  1383    1395    0   gattgAAATTttc   TCR;CPP 2
000009.1    Ca3CNSNP430205  3334    3343    0   tATATAtata  AT-Hook 3
000009.2    Ca3CNSNP430205  3334    3343    0   tATATAtata  AT-Hook 3
000009.3    Ca3CNSNP430205  3334    3343    0   tATATAtata  AT-Hook 3
```

Comment: thank you so much @RomanPerekhrest  ,  it works well , can u elobrate printf statement a bit.

Comment: I think `a[$1]` should be sufficient enough to record the duplicate count number without the need to introduce another variable `suf`, so `awk '{if(!a[$1]++){++c}; printf "%06d.%d\t%s\n",c,a[$1],$0}'` should work too

Comment: @etopylight, yes, that's a good hint, updated. Now, it's even more shorter

Comment: @a.k, welcome, see my update